# When aggregating C# datasets, how do I convert a DataSet into an DataTable Array for .Load()?

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, dataset

I am using .NET 4.0. I'm trying to aggregate many datasets with identical schemas into a single dataset. Each source dataset should contain the same three tablenames as all the other datasets. For now, I may assume the data will all be unique, even across tables and datasets. I'm trying to use the .Load() function but I am stuck on the third parameter. I may be misunderstanding what .Load() is actually intended for, and if this isn't the best way to accomplish this task, then by all means let me know. Here's what I have so far:

```
private AccessFileCollection accessFileCollection;
private DataSet allAccessData;

public void AggregateCollection()
{
    foreach (AccessFile accessFile in accessFileCollection.Files.Values)
    {
        foreach (DataTable dt in accessFile.Dataset.Tables)
        {
            if (allAccessData.Tables[dt.TableName] == null)
            { allAccessData.Tables.Add(new DataTable(dt.TableName)); }
        }
        allAccessData.Load(accessFile.Dataset.CreateDataReader(), 
            LoadOption.PreserveChanges,
            accessFile.Dataset.Tables);
    }
}

//AccessFileCollection is a custom class which implements .GetEnumerator() and also contains:
private Dictionary<int, AccessFile> accessFileCollection; //With a get/set called ".Files"

//AccessFile is a custom class that contains:
private DataSet ds; //With a get/set called ".Dataset"
```

MSDN gives us the method signature of .Load():

```
public void Load(
    IDataReader reader,
    LoadOption loadOption,
    params DataTable[] tables // <-- How do I satisfy this? What do I provide out of accessFile?
)
```

So, my questions again are:
- Is .Load() appropriate here?
- what is the best way to satisfy the DataTable[] requirements?
- Why doesn't Microsoft just let me throw an entire dataset into the third parameter? A Dataset already contains a list of datatable arrays!

Comment: Have you tried providing the `Tables` property of the data set? Something like `dataSet.Tables.OfType<DataTable>().ToArray()`.

Comment: It seems to... Once I get past this next error, I'll know more: "Table myTable does not belong to this DataSet." I think this is either because I didn't initialize my target dataset properly or else .Tables.OfType<DataTable>().ToArray() may be creating the array differently than I expect. Updating code above.

Comment: It is probably trying to add an unassociated `DataTable` to a `DataSet`. Those tables will be associated with the source data set.

Comment: In your opinion, is this the wrong approach to aggregating datasets or is this just a matter of working out the syntax? I'm willing to use Linq, too, but I am not any good with it.

Comment: It has been a long while since I worked with data sets, but I might look at doing it per table using the `DataTable.Merge` or `ImportRow` methods.

Comment: I went with merge. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

- What is the best way to satisfy the DataTable[] requirements?

A DataSet already contains DataTables. You can try tablesArray from bellow (having DataSet accessFile)

```
DataTableCollection tableCollection = accessFile.Tables;
DataTable[] tablesArray = null;
tableCollection.CopyTo(tablesArray, 0);
```